# How to DECLARE TYPE myType AS TABLE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use table-valued parameter to pass a column to "IN" clause in SQL Server. To do so I need to declare a type of table.
The SQL expression:

```
DECLARE TYPE myType AS TABLE( myid varchar(50) NULL);
```

is giving the error:

> 'myType' is not a recognized CURSOR option.

Replacing DECLARE to CREATE is working good.
Using "CREATE" is requiring to drop this type in any next SQL calls like:

```
IF TYPE_ID('myType') IS NOT NULL DROP TYPE myType;
```

But I would like to use the type "myType" just within this SQL expression only.
How to declare a type as table without creating it permanently and without deleting it in all requests?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create this permanently?  There is no way of creating one on the fly scoped to a single request

Comment: I tend to have a bunch of generic single and two-column table types for various queries and procedures, then you don't have to declare them every time

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE requires the following sinthax:

```
DECLARE @LastName NVARCHAR(30), @FirstName NVARCHAR(20), @Country NCHAR(2);
```

With `DECLARE`, you can:

- To assign a variable name(using `@`).
- To assign a Variable Type
- To assign a `NULL` default Variable value

So `"DECLARE TYPE"` is not a valid statement.

Have a look to ***temporary tables*** in sql.
You can create a temporary table in sql with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    name VARCHAR(50),
    age int,
    gender VARCHAR (50)

)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT name, age, gender
FROM student
WHERE gender = 'Male'
```

With a temporary table, you can store a subset of data from a standard table for a certain period of time.

Temporary tables are stored inside `“tempdb”` which is a system database.

Comment: And you can declare a table variable: `DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(FirstName VARCHAR(50), ...`

Comment: @Tyron78, is there a way to DECLARE a new table as type of "@MyTable"?

Comment: @BlackMath, since DECLARE TYPE is not valid is there a way to first declare a table variable and then take a type of that table?

Comment: @ildar no, you can not declare a type - you can only create it. But what exactly do you want to achieve? If you need to pass a table as parameter, why not creating it in the DB (since you mentioned that worked fine)?